# Making a div slide using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, interactive

I know this may have already been answered but I haven't been able to find one that quite fits what I'm trying to do. Pretty much I want to make a div slide to the side after 2 seconds using js. This is what I have now;

```js
setTimeout("slide()", 1000)

function slide() {

  var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
  myElement.style.left = 200px;

  setTimeout("slide()", 2000)

};
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">box</div>
```

Anything I'm doing wrong or a link to a question that answers this would be a big help! Thanks

Comment: If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have:

```
myElement.style.left = 200px;
```

It should be:

```
myElement.style.left = '200px';
```

Also this:

```
setTimeout("slide()", 2000);
```

Should really just be this:

```
setTimeout(slide, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes a function as its first argument, but you pass a string. Even if it wasn't a string, it would misfire, because of the `()`

The proper way to use setTimeout is like this:

```
setTimeout(slide, 1000);

function slide() {

  var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
  myElement.style.left = '200px'; // Fix this too!

  setTimeout(slide, 2000)

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not properly using `setTimeout` function.  Use style string.

```
setTimeout(function(){slide();}, 1000);
function slide() {
  var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
  myElement.style.left = "200px";
  setTimeout(function(){slide();}, 2000);
}
```

or simply

```
setTimeout(slide, 1000);
function slide() {
  var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
  myElement.style.left = "200px";
  setTimeout(slide, 2000);
}
```

Why use the first option?  Pass parameters that way:

```
setTimeout(function(){slide(2000);}, 1000);
function slide(delaytime) {
  var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
  myElement.style.left = "200px";
  setTimeout(function(){slide(delaytime);}, delaytime);
}
```